# Update a column in table based on column from another table

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables.  Patients Table has PatientName, Age, and Sex.  Visits Table has PatientName, SpecialistName, DateOfVisit, and an Age Column which doesn't have any values in it yet.  I want to update the Age Column in the Visits Table based on that patient's age from the Patients Table.  Here is my best guess, but the message I receive is:

> "Operation must use an updateable query."

```
update visits v
set v.age = (
select p.age from
patients p where v.pname = p.pname);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that column be populated with the patient's age as of the date of visit?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `MSSQL`

```
UPDATE v
SET v.Age = p.Age
FROM visits V INNER JOIN patients p
ON v.pname = p.pname
```

If you are using `MySQL`

```
UPDATE visits V
INNER JOIN patients p
ON v.pname = p.pname
SET v.Age = p.Age
```

[See this Link: **UPDATE with JOIN**](http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `from` clause as below:

```
update visits v
set v.age = p.age
from patients p 
where v.pname = p.pname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

```
update visits v, patients p set v.age = p.age where v.pname = p.pname;
```